# wpf:attached properties

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

IS attached properties enable to modify the properties of a root element or parent element in the logical tree in any one of the child .
Just wanted to check whether I have understood it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well an attached property is nothing more than a value you can attach to a `DependencyObject`. You can however handle value changed, of the attached property, in order to run your specific logic (this is also called [attached behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF)).

The short answer yes.